# Laravel Multi-language Support

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get my website to support multiple languages, but my code does not work:

Route:

```
Route::get('lang/{lang}', function($lang){
    Session::put('lang', $lang);
    return Redirect::to('/');
});
```

Main page:

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('lang/fa') }}">[Farsi]</a>
<a href="{{ URL::to('lang/en') }}">[English]</a>
```

Language folders:

`fa` folder have `messages.php`:

```
return array(
    'mainpage'=>'صفحه اصلی',
);
```

`en` folder have `messages.php`:

```
return array(
    'mainpage'=>'Main Page`,
);
```

Now I am trying to use this array to have multi-language support and I am using this code to switch between languages:

```
{{ Lang::get('messages.mainpage') }}
```

Comment: Are you receiving an error?

Comment: @JosephIdziorek no, i dont get any error, problem is laravel could not switch to other languages by session or change runtime

Comment: @Joseph Idziorek Problem solved, i'm post solution

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, Thanks to @rezakho,

after adding this line to `route.php`:

```
if ( Session::has('lang') ) {
        App::setLocale(Session::get('lang'));
    }
```

or you change `before` on `filters.php` file:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    if ( Session::has('lang') ) {
        App::setLocale(Session::get('lang'));
    }
});
```